# Giving admin power on users with some specific role to users with another specific role

Tags: liferay, roles, user-roles

I created RoleX, and I joined users to RoleX. Later I created RoleAdminX and now I want when users which have RoleAdminX after logged to control panel might manage to only users which have RoleX. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do exactly what you are asking to do... What the RoleAdminX is expected to manage? Should it put and remove users from the RoleX? Should it also be able to change users attributes like name, e-mail and permissions?

Comment: RoleAdminX should be able to change users attribute like name, e-mail etc.

Comment: What version of Liferay are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Roles cannot do that; what you are looking for are *organizations*. To see how they work and can solve your need, follow the steps:

## Creating users and organization

- In the Control Panel, go into "Users and organizations"
- Create three users: `X user`, `X admin user` and `no X user`.
- Now, click in the same "Add" button you used before. However, instead of clicking in "User", click in "Regular organization".

  [image: Menu showing "Regular organization" option]
- Name this organization "X" and save it. When you go back to the "User and organizations" section, you'll see the organization listed above all users:

  [image: Organization "X" listed]

## Assign users to organization

Now that we have an organization, we should add our users to it.

- Click on the organization name. There will be a menu in the left.

  [image: Organization menu]
- In the menu, click on "Assign users"
- Click in the "Available" tab
- Select the users "X user" and "X admin user". Do not select the "no X user"
- Click in "Update associations"

## Assign admin roles

Now we are going to give our "X admin user" powers to manage other users.

- Go back to the organization editing page, where the aforementioned menu is found.
- Click in "Assign organization roles"
- Click in "Organization Administrator"
- Click in the "Available" tab
- Select the "x admin user". Click in "Update associations"

## Testing

Does it work? Let us see!

- Go back to the organization editing page, where the aforementioned menu is found.
- Click in the "Actions" button from "x admin user". In the menu, click in "Impersonate user." A new tab will appear; in this tab, all actions you execute will be done as if you were logged in with the "x admin user".

[image: Action menu for a user]

- In the newly open page, there will be a "Go to" button at the top right. Click on it. In the menu, click on "Control Panel".

[image: Where go to go to Control Panel.]

- You'll see what you are usually is found in the Control Panel of a common user: sections for editing the own user's data as well as sections. sections for editing the *user's site* and its contents (but not other sites!) At the end, however, there will be an unusual section (for common users to have access, I mean): *Users and Organizations*. Click on it.

[image: Control Panel sections]

- You'll see a listing containing the "x" organization. Note that neither the admin user you were logged with, nor the "no x user" are listed here. Click on the organization.

[image: Organizations presented to user]

- Here, you'll see all the users added to the "x" organization. Click on the action menu and see how you can edit the user, handle user sites and permissions etc. If you want to take users out from the organization, or invite others in, just use the "Assign Users" option previously explained.

[image: Users being listed to "x admin user"]

All the last steps were executed as if you were the "x admin user". If you doubt it, just log out and log in as the "x admin user" :)

You cannot, however, create new users or delete existing ones. This is a task to the administrator.

(Here I used Liferay 6.1 because the version of Liferay 6.2 I have here has some annoying bug that impedes the x admin user of arriving at the Control Panel, but the idea should be the same.)